# Cómo analizar cada posición en una matriz

Tags: java, fórmulas-de-matriz

estoy haciendo un programa para analizar matrices, es una tarea. El proposito es que diga si es Upper triangular, Strictly upper triangular o ninguna. Está sencillo pero soy muy nueva en esto y no me sale, concretamente tengo problemas con la parte de analizar cada posición en la matriz.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que en las posiciones donde i sea mayor que j, se compruebe que el valor es cero, si es así el valor de X no cambia (quiere decir que es upper o strictly upper, se definirá a continuación), si en alguna de esas posiciones el valor es diferente a cero entonces X se vuelve uno (quiere decir que no es upper ni strictly upper).

Después, se debe diferenciar entre upper y strictly, entonces en las posiciones donde i sea igual a j se va a comprobar que hay ceros, en caso de que sí, el valor de X se mantendrá igual a 0. Si hay otro valor, entonces cambiará a 2.

----Estoy haciendo esto en JAVA

---i se refiere a la posición de la columna

---j se refiere a la posición de la fila

---x es una variable que no proviene de ninguna otra parte del código, según yo :b la ocupo para hacer que el If se siga repitiendo o no dependiendo del caso, además para identificar al final qué tipo de matriz es, eso lo hice con un swithc

```css
if (matrix[i][j]) {
  if (i > j) {
    if (matrix[i][j]=0) {
      x=0;
    }
    else {
      x=1;
    }
  }
}

if (matrix[i][j]) {
  if (i=j) {
    if (matrix[i][j]=0) {
      x=0;
    }
    else {
      x=2;
    }
  }
}
```

Esta es una matriz Upper triangular, al lado están las coordenadas i,j. Como pueden ver, en las posiciones que deben ser cero i > j.

> > 1---3---6
> >
> > 0---2---7
> >
> > 0---0---7
>
> 0,0---0,1---0,2
>
> 1,0---1,1---1,2
>
> 2,0---2,1---2,2

En el caso de la Strictly Upper triangular, no solo las posiciones donde i>j son cero, también las que i=j.

> > 0---3---6
> >
> > 0---0---7
> >
> > 0---0---0
>
> 0,0---0,1---0,2
>
> 1,0---1,1---1,2
>
> 2,0---2,1---2,2

Esas son las propiedades que intento utilizar en mi código, intento que un if dicte una posición que va a ir cambiando con cada repetición, después analice si se cumple i>j o i=j y después que diga si es cero u otra cosa.

Comment: Buenas, ¿podrías especificar de dónde sale 'x'?¿Influye en la matriz o es una variable aparte?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes varios  errores, en primer lugar en `if` es `=` no `==`. 
Después, si la matriz es de enteros qué sentido tiene preguntar si es  igual a " "?

También deberías especificar qué valores quieres para `x` y mostrar el código completo